# Recent syntax error using Python2 vs. Python3

Tags: python, syntax

I have a script using openpyxl to add rows to an existing xlsx spreadsheet. It was running fine a couple of weeks ago: however, when I run it now, it starts to give me different syntax error in Python2 and Python3.

The problem I have is that the syntax error is pointing to the import packages rather than somewhere in code.

Any suggestion on how to fix these syntax issues?

Error with Python2

```
IDA-Data host$ python2 add_name_excel_dirs.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 62, in <module>
        import os
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 400, in <module>
        import UserDict
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 116, in <module>
        import _abcoll
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 662
        def append(self, value: object) -> object:
                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Error with Python3 when running the same script:

```
IDA-Data host$ python3 add_name_excel_dirs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_name_excel_dirs.py", line 5, in <module>
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from openpyxl.compat.numbers import NUMPY, PANDAS
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/compat/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .strings import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/compat/strings.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .numbers import NUMERIC_TYPES
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/compat/numbers.py", line 28, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.io.pytables import HDFStore, get_store, read_hdf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 918
    def append(self, key: object, value: object, format: object = None, append: object = True, columns: object = None,
              ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Comment: I am using MacOS with Python2 pre-installed. Python3 was installed later.

Comment: It looks like you've made a mess with installing different interpreters and packages linked to incorrect interpreters. `def append(self, value: object) -> object` should never work in Python 2.

Comment: If that is the case, should I uninstall both python versions and re-install them?

Comment: Very weird, it seems that `: object` has been appended to a bunch of places. I would indeed recommend reinstalling Python.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. When I run these within virtual env. with python3, the scripts are working fine. I will uninstall my python outside of the virtual env.